# SQL SERVER - Return OUTPUT INSERTED.* with JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this SQL server query which works fine.
It returns the complete inserted row.

```
INSERT INTO Comments
  (
    ImageID,
    UserId1,
    CommentTxt
  ) OUTPUT INSERTED.* 

SELECT 1620,
       @userid1,
       'abc'
```

But I need to return a *joined information* to that inserted row ( I also want the user who commented)

So I've tried this :

```
INSERT INTO Comments
  (
    ImageID,
    UserId1,
    CommentTxt
  )OUTPUT INSERTED.* JOIN Users u ON INSERTED.userid1 = u.UserID
SELECT 1620,
       @userid1,
       'abc'
```

**Result :**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'JOIN'.

**Question:**

Is it possible to use `OUTPUT`  with `JOIN` ?

<sub>Basically I'm after  : `Inserted.*,relevant_user.*` 
In the same hit.</sub>

--
NB
I *don't* want to get the scope_identity and re-select the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is guaranteed to be exactly one matching row in `Users` then you can use `MERGE`.

If there might be 0 matching rows or greater than one this will not have the same semantics as your desired syntax because the join is carried out before the insert not after.

```
WITH Source
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES(1620, @userid1, 'abc')) 
                    V(ImageID, UserId1, CommentTxt)
                JOIN Users u
                  ON v.userid1 = u.UserID)
MERGE INTO Comments
USING Source
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( ImageID,
           UserId1,
           CommentTxt )
  VALUES (ImageID,
          UserId1,
          CommentTxt)
OUTPUT Source.*;
```

Comment: Yes a specific  comment can be written by only 1 user. BTW - thanks :)

Comment: Can you please explain this ? `ON 1 = 0` ?

Comment: It's always false so always goes to the `NOT MATCHED`

Comment: Oh. Forcing insert . :-)

Comment: Martin , I do see the joined data , but why  don't I see the `inserted.*` data ? https://i.imgur.com/BXfcD3r.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir add `INSERTED.*,` to the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but now the ORM (dapper) will not know  how to split those columns into 2 entities ( since it has duplicate columns )

Comment: So don't use `*` select the columns you need